# BluetoothSerial ionic2 - can't connect to device

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, ionic2, bluez

i'm trying to use Bluez (python) on a raspberry pi to receive data with bluetooth from a ionic2 app. I'm using the built in Bluetooth from "native ionic" which is the `bluetoothSerial` framework from Cordova

I can't receive any data on the rasp. I'm using `list()` to check if the device is connected to the rasp (it return true).

I'm using write to send a "hello world" message.

The Ionic2 script:

```
   BluetoothSerial.connect("B8:27:EB:F7:3B:B5");
    BluetoothSerial.write("hello world").then(this.success, this.failure);
```

After the write, my callback succes is called which means that the data was correctly sent.
I was wondering on which bluetooth port the ionic2 app send the data. Bluez need a specific port to listen to.

Comment: Do you mean you cannot connect or you cannot receive data?

Comment: It seems that I cannot connect

Comment: I'm using list() to check if the device is connected to the rasp (it return true). What do you mean by this? It returns you true but you say you cannot connect

Comment: Well in debug mode it's connected when i'm using list, but when I use 'isConnected()' it is not. That's the weird thing.

Comment: https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial Is this the plugin you are using? Provide more info so people can help you better

Comment: Yes it is, it's mentioned in the ionic native component in the section BluetoothSerial

Comment: What I suggest is that instead of using BluetoothSerial through `ionic-native`, import it directly from the author github `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-bluetooth-serial`

Comment: Not too sure if `ionic-native` `connect(macAddress_or_uuid)` returns any success or error message but the plugin does: `bluetoothSerial.connect(macAddress_or_uuid, connectSuccess, connectFailure);`

Comment: Take a look here: https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial